# Jquery advice in selecting divs

Tags: jquery, accordion

so I am trying to make an accordian like effect with a punch of panels, the action is initiated by clicking a panel on top of the panel to be opened. This all works fine, but the problem I am having is selecting the other open panel and closing it while opening the new panel. The new panel also gets closed!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.content_accrd').css({"height":"0px"});
$('.paneltop').click( function() {
    $(this).css({"background-position":"0px -21px"})
    .siblings().animate({"height":"100px"}, 200)
    .parent().children(".content_accrd").animate({"height":"0px"});
})
})
```

Comment: FWIW, jquery ui already has an accordion effect: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion

Comment: I am trying to make my own through this method

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.content_accrd').css({"height":"0px"});
    $('.paneltop').click( function() {
        $(this).css({"background-position":"0px -21px"})
            .parent().children(".content_accrd").animate({"height":"0px"})
            .siblings().animate({"height":"100px"}, 200);
     })
})
```

close the other open panels first, then open the one that was clicked.

Comment: try this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gaBPp/2/
(just guessing at your html based on your script code)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose excluding your current clicked DIV will also work. But that's not so important.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.content_accrd').css({"height":"0px"});
$('.paneltop').click( function() {
    $(this).css({"background-position":"0px -21px"})
    .siblings().animate({"height":"100px"}, 200).not($(this))
    .parent().children(".content_accrd").animate({"height":"0px"});
  })
})
```

I don't know if you have already seen this article:
http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/
It offers some useful performance tips which helped me in my learning process.

Also you definitely should try to make plugin yourself, it's also a big step towards understanding jQuery more deep.

http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/jquery-plugin-boilerplate-oop/

Comment: looked like it might work but has the same problem, thanks for your help though